# Does looking at someone produce any physical force?

Tags: vision

I was driving home one day and it just popped into my head, does looking at someone or something produce any kind of physical force. If someone could answer this question that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

No. When you look at someone, you are receiving photons emitted / reflected from that someone's body. Those photons have already been emitted. Whether or not you choose to detect those photons has no impact on the body that emitted them.

Here's another way to look at it. Suppose that looking at someone really does produce a physical force. Then put that someone on Jupiter. If you're looking at Jupiter, you exert a force on him, but if you look at the moon, you don't. That violates causality - you can exert an instantaneous force from far away - and isn't possible.

Comment: The part about instantaneous force doesn't really make any sense to me.  There's no requirement for the force to be instantaneous.

Comment: @StephenG If it isn't instantaneous, what could it be? Suppose it took light travel time to exert a force on the guy in Jupiter by looking at him. But during that time, he moves from Jupiter to Saturn. Do you exert a force on him or not? The idea becomes inconsistent.

Comment: We don't generally accept the idea of instantaneous transmission of force anyway is what I mean (which does tie into your point, of course).  Whether the idea was inconsistent would require a model for the way the force operates and that's a mute point.

Comment: I agree with @StephenG, the second paragraph creates more confusion than clarity.

Comment: I do not want to make this into an answer, because I do not know enough biology. It is true that the brain and our neutrons work with electromagnetic frequencies , see this for example http://www.measurement.sk/2005/S2/Lipkova.pdf . Maybe in future research a directionality might be found for these frequencies that could be  controlled by what we call "looking". At present there is no such physical evidence afaik